# using uniqid function to change filename and then echo

Tags: php, html, image, image-uploading

How could I build the uniqid function into this uploading script?

My goal is to upload a image to a server and have the image renamed to random characters, then have the link to the image echoed out at the end once it has been uploaded.

So here is how I'm picturing it:
Upload image.png > 
script processes image.png and uses uniqid function to give it a random name like 3ia8d3awd.png > 
then the script echos the new images name and links the image in an  tag once it has been uploaded to the directory.

Here is the script:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "..img/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != 
"jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], 
$target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has 
been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

I know this script was meant to take image names as is and upload them but if you could help modify this for me. I think it would be the uniqid function for this but I may be wrong. I'm still new to PHP and have spent a good two hours trying to figure this one out; thank you.

EDIT: Was informed that more_entropy function will supply more unique names.

Comment: "Warning This function does not guarantee uniqueness of return value. Since most systems adjust system clock by NTP or like, system time is changed constantly. Therefore, it is possible that this function does not return unique ID for the process/thread. Use more_entropy to increase likelihood of uniqueness." - http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Better use a UUID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the top of your code:

```
$newFileName = uniqueid('',TRUE);
$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] = $newFileName;
```

This should assign a new unique name to the file. Off course I didn't tested it to see if it interferes with the file extension but let me know how it works.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function unique_id() in directory on line 3. Here is the edited bit on the top, I think I did the right spot:  <?php
$target_dir = "..img/";
$newFileName = unique_id('',TRUE);
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] = $newFileName);
$uploadOk = 1;

Comment: Sorry, I meant `uniqueid()` not `unique_id()`. The answer has been edited.

Comment: Same error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function uniqueid() in directory on line 3.  I tried uniqid() and I got another error with my file size check but when it failed on undefined file size, it did not create a crash log.

Comment: Try it without the stuff inside. Just `uniqueid()` not `uniqueid('', TRUE)` and see if that helps. It shouldn't matter though.

Comment: Tried `uniqueid()` instead of `uniqueid('', TRUE)` and got the same call to undefined function uniqueid() .

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? You should check php.ini and see if that function has, for some strange reason been disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified script, just inserted the user defined function to generate a random and most probably unique name there are 4 segments of names and each segment is 6 characters long you can customize these settings in function uniqueName

```
<?php

function genName($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

function uniqueName()
{
   $temp = '';
   for($i = 0;$i<4;$i++) //number of random segments
      $temp .= '_'.genName(6); // length of each segment

  return $temp;
}

$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] = uniqueName();

$target_dir = "..img/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != 
"jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], 
$target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has 
been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A modified and untested version of the original that has a small utility function to help generate random ( and hopefully unique ) names for uploaded files.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_FILES ) ){
        /*
            generate a random name for new files
        */
        function createname( $prefix='',$name, $length=16 ){
            /* random chars with optional prefix & length */
            return $prefix.substr( sha1( $name . uniqid( $prefix, true ) . time() ), 0, $length );
        }

        try{
            /* Only permit these file extensions */
            $allowed=array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');
            /* Do not allow files larger than this */
            $maxsize=500000;
            /* optional prefix to generated file name - can be '' */
            $prefix='img_';

            $target_dir = "..img/";

            /* Get reference to file as object for convenience */
            $file=(object)$_FILES['fileToUpload'];

            $name=$file->name;
            $size=$file->size;
            $tmp=$file->tmp_name;
            $type=$file->type;
            $error=$file->error;



            /* File extension */
            $ext=pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
            $filename=pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_FILENAME );

            /* target will be similar to "..img/img_a7119f62b2810c68.jpg" */
            $targetfile=createname( $prefix, $filename ) . '.' . $ext;
            $targetpath=$target_dir . $targetfile;

            if( $error==UPLOAD_ERR_OK && is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) ){

                /* Is the file an image? */
                list( $w, $h, $t, $a ) = getimagesize( $tmp );
                if( !$w or !$h ) throw new Exception('File is not an image');

                /* Correct file extension? */
                if( !in_array( $ext, $allowed ) ) throw new Exception('Incorrect file extension - only '.implode(', ',$allowed).' are permitted');


                /* Does file already exist ( unlikely if using unique random names ) */
                if( realpath( $targetpath ) ) throw nex Exception('File already exists');

                /* Is file too large? */
                if( $size > $maxsize )throw new Exception('File is too large');

                /* save the file */
                $status=move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $targetpath );
                echo $status ? "The file has been saved: <a href='$targetpath' target='_blank'>{$targetfile}</a>" : "Sorry - there was a problem saving the file. Check permissions on folder.";


            } else {
                throw new Exception('upload failed');
            }
        }catch( Exception $e ){
            exit( $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }
?>
```